# Dynamic Includes

Tags: jekyll

I've seen some posts saying you can only pass literal strings to Jekyll's front matter include statement like so:

```
{% include mypage.ext %}
```

However, I have the following HTML layout for pretty much every page:

```
    <section id="feature">
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12 alpha omega">
                {% include myfile.ext %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12 alpha omega">
                {{ content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This would be painful to have to include in every single page in order to achieve the layout I'm looking for. The included file would be relevant to the current page, so I was hoping someone knew of some kind of way to do this.  Of course it'd be something along the lines of:

```
{% include {{page.file}} %}
```

I've seen some other posts saying this just can't happen though.

So, I just want to be able to dynamically load includes in Jekyll.

Edit: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/176

Comment: Do your includes have a few variations utilized over and over or does each page have a unique include? I have a similar set up and used a "when" case argument with a simple logic test so that when front matter condition "a" was set then it included file "matched-for-a.ext".

Comment: for example:

    `{% case template %}
    {% when 'index' %}
    Welcome
    {% when 'product' %}
    {{ product.vendor | link_to_vendor }} / {{ product.title }}
    {% else %}
    {{ page_title }}
    {% endcase %}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently intentionally not possible, as the maintainers of Jekyll don't want the project to get *too* dynamic. You can read [this comment & thread](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/176#issuecomment-11798538) for a bit of background. The suggestion that qrush (the maintainer) gives is to use rails or sinatra. Probably not the answer you're looking for, but that's the current status.

If you want to use a plugin, there's one that will let you do this [here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/176#issuecomment-6757780)

Comment: Yeah, I've been watching the pull requests and comments. The makers really don't want it in there. Big shame.

Answer (score 8):

This will be perhaps possible when [that issue](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1464) will be fixed with [the pull request #1495](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/pull/1495) which propose exactly what you are looking for : `{% include {{page.file}} %}`

Comment: Yep, works for me: `{% include my.html %}` where `my.html` has to be in `_includes/my.html`. Thanks!